# Real part of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, rational-functions

Suppose we have the complex number $c$ and a rationale function $F(c)$. Could I say that $F(\mathrm{Re}(c))=\mathrm{Re}(F(c))$. Is there a proof of this?

Thank you!

Comment: Take $F(c)=ic$. Then $F(Re(c))=iRe(c)$, while $Re(F(c))=Re(ic)=-Im(c)$.

Comment: Even with real coefficients $F(c)=1/c$ gives $F(Re(c))=1/Re(c)$, while $Re(F(c))=Re(1/c)=Re(c)/|c|$

Comment: Such symmetry is almost never true.  $f(Re(z)) = Re(f(z))$ would mean that for any real $x$ then $f(Re(x)) = f(x) = Re(f(x))$ s $f(x)$ is real for every real $x$.  Just take a function where that *isn't* true.  Let $f(z) = z + i$ then $Re(f(a+bi)) = Re(a + (b+1)i) = a$ but $f(Re(a+bi)) = f(a) = a + i$.  Not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** if the functions are allowed to have complex valued coefficients, e.g. $F(z)=i$

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}\Re(F(z))=0\not=i=F(\Re(z)).$$

**No** if the function can have complex valued arguments, e.g. $F(z)=z^2$

$$\Re(F(i))=-1\not=0=F(\Re(i)).$$

**Yes** if the functions have real valued coefficients only and only real valued arguments are considered. For a given real number $x$ in the domain of $F$, we have $F(x)\in\Bbb R$ as well. Therefore

$$F(\Re(x))=\underbrace{F(x)}_{\in \,\Bbb R}=\Re(F(x)).$$